# Creating StateListDrawables for multiple components of a custom ViewGroup from a common resource

Tags: android, statelistdrawable

I have created a class which extends ViewGroup. One of the functions of this MyCustomViewGroup class is acting as a container for a nested class MyButton which extends Button.

I setup the custom properties for MyCustomViewGroup from a custom AttributeSet in the normal manner. One of the attributes defines the StateListDrawable to use for the background of instances of the MyButton nested class. I store this in a Class variable mMyButtonBackground.

```
public class MyCustomViewGroup extends ViewGroup {
    private Drawable mMyButtonBackground;
    ...
```

Each time I create a new instance of MyButton in MyCustomViewGroup I set it's background.

```
    MyButton myButton = new MyButton(context);
    myButton.setBackground(mMyButtonBackground);
```

At run time, the StateListDrawable only seems to be working for the most recently added instance of MyButton.

For example say I create 4 instances of MyButton in MyCustomViewGroup. If I click on MyButton number 4, it's background changes as defined in the StateListDrawable. If I click on MyButton 1 to 3, their backgrounds do not change but MyButton number 4's does.

Logically this would suggest it is a mutability problem. All the MyButton instances are sharing the same StateListDrawable stored in mMyButtonBackground. Considering this, I've tried:

```
    MyButton myButton = new MyButton(context);
    Drawable myButtonBackground = mMyButtonBackground.mutate();
    myButton.setBackground(myButtonBackground);
```

This did not solve the issue though. I've also tried specifically casting it as a StateListDrawable:

```
    MyButton myButton = new MyButton(context);
    StateListDrawable myButtonBackground = (StateListDrawable)mMyButtonBackground.mutate();
    myButton.setBackground(myButtonBackground);
```

This also did not solve the problem. In my research trying to solve this problem I have have read [this article by Romain Guy on Drawable mutations](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2009/05/drawable-mutations.html). I would have thought that since a StateListDrawable is a subclass of Drawable, I should be able to apply the same approach, but I can't seem to get it working. What am I missing?

Comment: No it isn't static, but I've now edited the question to make that clearer though. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following pskink answer, the problem is that you use the same `Drawable` instance. When you set the `Drawable` as the background, the `View` will register itself as a listener for that `Drawable` to receive events(to take in consideration the new stat of a `Drawable`, also requiring a redraw of the `View`). So, your single instance `StateListDrawable` will always have as a callback the last `View` for which is set as background. That's why it works for the last `Button`, but it also redraws the same `Button` when you act upon the other `Buttons` as the `Drawable` triggers a invalidate on its callback `View`.

You could simply avoid this by creating a new `StateListDrawable` for each `Button`. In the wrapper container you could just pass an attribute with a `String` representing the name of the `StateListDrawable` to use as the background, store it and use it when creating new `Buttons`:

```
String mBtnDrawable = ""; //initialize in the constructor

// creating new Buttons
MyButton myButton = new MyButton(context);
int drawableId = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(mBtnDrawable, "drawable", getContext().getPackageName());
StateListDrawable bck = (StateListDrawable) getContext().getResources().getDrawable(drawableId); // maybe also mutate it?
myButton.setBackground(bck);
```

Comment: one small remark: you dont have to use .getResources().getIdentifier() which is rather slow, instead one could create an attribute with format="reference" and use it in the xml as myAttr="@drawable/something"

Comment: @pskink I know, but I was lazy, so I didn't looked in the docs for the direct method.

Comment: I'd been looking at trying to clone mMyButtonBackground each time I make a new instance of MyButton, which seemed like a nice neat solution, but the clone() method is hidden for StateListDrawables. @Luksprog: your solution is a good work around, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

you cannot share one instance of SLD with multiple Views, you need one SLD per View, sorry

Comment: Yes I thought that was the problem, thanks for confirming. As i said in my comment to Luksprog, I'd been looking at trying to clone mMyButtonBackground each time I make a new instance of MyButton, which seemed like a nice neat solution, but the clone() method is hidden for StateListDrawables. Is there a way a clone could be made?

Comment: clone is protected, extend SLD and us it there

Answer (score 1):

According to what Resources class does([Resources.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/res/Resources.java)), I find that the code below can solve your problem.

```
Drawable selector = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.setting_btn_pressed_selector);
view1.setBackgroundDrawable(selector.getConstantState().newDrawable());
view2.setBackgroundDrawable(selector.getConstantState().newDrawable());
view3.setBackgroundDrawable(selector.getConstantState().newDrawable());
```

But I don't know the side effect of this code. Anyone know? Feel free to leave any comment or point out my mistake.